# cv2.cameraCalibration using python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7

I am trying to learn how to do 3D and stereo camera calibration using openCV and python. Using 3 camera views of an 8x6 chessboard (7x5 interior corners), I was able to get `cv.calibrateCamera()` working OK but am totally stuck when I use cv2.
One of the steps is to find the chessboard corners. Whereas `cv.findChessboardCorners()` returns corners as a list of points, cv2 uses numpy arrays, and returns the points as a (35,1,2) numpy array. The parameters for cv2.calibrateCamera() are `object_points`, `image_points`, and `image_size`. I am supplying the object points in a `(3,35,3)` numpy array and the image points in a `(3,35,2)` numpy array. The image size is `(1632, 1224)`. Can anybody tell me what the problem is? The error I get isn't very useful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/pyCV/locv_book/ch11/calCamera2a.py", line 46, in <module>
  cv2.calibrateCamera(opts,ipts,size)
error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3173: error: (-215) ni >= 0
```

Answer (score 5):

Points need to be float32, in matrix form (N,2) and (N,3). You can convert to float32 this way:

```
points32 = np.array(points,dtype=np.float32)
```

Comment: Found this question in 2015, using OpenCV 2.4.10. I get a similar "cv2.error: ... calibration.cpp:3169: error: (-215) ni >= 0 in function cv::collectCalibrationData". The workaround was to reshape both arrays to (1, N, 3) and (1, N, 2) for object and image points respectively.